# SQL Server table export to Excel issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I am using 64-bit Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server 2008. And Using VS2008 + C# + .Net 2.0 + IIS 7.0 + ASP.Net. When executing the following statement, I met with the following error (the error occurs when accessing an aspx page), I am not sure whether it is 64-bit system specific issue?

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: unregistered OLE DB access interface "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("select * from  OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" + s_path.Trim() + "',sheet1$) where name is not null");   //e:\\test1.xls
            DataSet ds = SqlUtil.ExecuteDataset(Database.StrConn, CommandType.Text, sb.ToString());
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView_Tlinkmans.DataSource = ds;
                GridView_Tlinkmans.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: are you sure this is working on 32 bit computer?

Comment: I believe the OleDB JET Engine is 32-bit only...

Comment: Thanks marc_s, what is the solution for 64-bit platform when implementing the same behavior? Do you have any documents to prove OleDB JET Engine only for 32-bit platform?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, sure. Why you have this ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one or 2 issues:

You are querying OPENROWSET in SQL Server and you have x64 SQL Server, you *may* need the [MDAC to bridge SQL Server to ODBC/OLEDB](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91083/mdac-2-8-for-windows-x64). However, this says it is part of the OS for Win 2008+. I've had to install on Win 2003

Then you *probably* need this which is the closest to JET I know of: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en)

YMMV

Comment: "MDAC to bridge SQL Server to ODBC/OLEDB" is new to me. Do you have any related documents for newcomer? From the link you provided, I do not find any tutorials for beginner.

Comment: For "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable", it could be used to generate Excel file? From the name, it looks like that it is for Access, not Excel. :-)